# Create a Project in Eclipse that points to other Project's directory

Tags: eclipse, import, project, hyperlink, directory

I have a project (say Project1) in Eclipse that contains a "/sample" folder in it. The /sample folder contains sample projects in it.

What I want to do is that, I want to Import any of the sample project (say Sample1) in Eclipse in such a way that eclipse will links to the /sample directory of Project1. So any change that I made in Sample1 will update the /sample folder of the Project1.

Comment: I don't understand: if Project1 is already located in "sample/", then any change to it will change "sample/" as well -- what am I missing?

Comment: Project1 is the main project that contains /sample folder in it. Inside the /sample folder there are Sample Projects that I want to Import

Comment: Sorry, I meant Sample1 is already in "sample/".  Can't you just import Sample1 like you did for Project1?

Comment: No .. If I try to Import it through Eclipse and give the path of the /sample project it gives following message "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has the concept of linked files/folders. See [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-45.htm). Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse recognizes when changes have been made in a project source file from outside -- it will prompt you to reload it -- so that should not be an issue even if you have the folder open as part of two separate projects at the same time.  I don't like the editor in eclipse but sometimes use it for other reasons, so I do this all the time (externally edit files I have open in eclipse).  It is relatively hassle free, if you consider hitting F5 not much of a hassle.

WRT to connecting the two, on linux eclipse respects (soft) links, so you could use, eg:

```
ln -s project1/sample1 sample
```

in your project directory.

This is the same on OSX.  I believe newer Windows OS's have some equivalent, but don't ask me what it is (the concept is "soft link" or "sym(bolic) link".  If you are using cygwin's msys shell, `ln` *may* work there.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Looks like there are details WRT to Windows (and cygwin) there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is something that I have discussed with the team but before going with it I am just looking for Eclipse provides linking by itself. If I doesn't found anything in Eclipse then I will surely go with this solution.